# How Can I Hide a Loading Overlay When User Returns to Page via Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Background

To ease page transitions on my web app, I'm building in an overlay/loading icon layer. It is visible initially, and I hide it after my JS is finished loading. I then show it when any `a` elements are clicked. Screencap below:

[image]

---

## Code

**HTML**

```
    ...
</head>
<body class="preload">
    <loading><div class="pulse-loader visible"></div></loading>
```

**Hide on Page Load**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("preload");
}, 120);
```

**Show on Click**

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    $("body").addClass("preload");
});
```

---

## Goal

When the user clicks the back button, I'd like for the page to realize that and re-hide the loading overlay/icon. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems like you are arbitrarily showing/hiding the "loader." Why not bind it to the actual transition?

Comment: What transition do you mean?

Comment: Page transition, apparently

Comment: Using `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: Gotta give the OP props for including the gif so people can visually see what he's talking about AND including code + the goal of his question. I wish all questions were formatting in the manner. Well done @AndyM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

The answer is the [pageshow/pagehide](https://webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/) events. WebKit introduced these, in part to deal with this exact problem. There is a load, and unload event. I only need the load event for my purposes, though I could use the unload even to show my loading overlay.

### Code

I place this in my script file (both inside or outside of the jQuery document.ready wrapper):

```
if ("onpagehide" in window) {
    window.addEventListener("pageshow", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('body').removeClass('preload');  }, 120);
    }, false);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('body').removeClass('preload'); }, 120);
    }, false);
}
```

The pageLoaded function is fired on page load, even when the page is reached via the back button.

**Browser Compat:**

I've tested this in Edge, Firefox, on Windows, and Safari on OSX, and it works.

## EDIT:

This is currently broken in Chrome. There's a [**bug ticket**](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344507&can=5&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), but it hasn't had much movement recently. If you'd like to see it fixed, upvote the ticket!